# Java Regex tweaking

Tags: java, regex

I'm not all that great at regular expressions, so I've been digging around for some help.

What I need is to pull any string encapsulated within double curly-braces {{ }}. For example, I have a String value as so:

```
String text = "This is my sample {{text1}} text {{text2}}.";
```

This is my regex:

```
String regex = "\\{\\{.*\\}\\}";
```

This is what I do with the code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher match = p.matcher(text);
while (match.find()) {
    System.out.println(match.group());
}
```

My needed output is:

```
{{text1}}
{{text2}}
```

But I think the regex is finding and locating both ends of the String value, because it returns me this instead:

```
{{text1}} text {{text2}}
```

when I print out the value. How should I tweak my regex to capture what I need?

Also, I have no idea how many {{texts}} there will be in any given String, this is a sample with 2 but there might be any number, perhaps even none at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String regex = "\\{\\{.*?\\}\\}";
```

Note the `?` after the `.*`. This makes it non-greedy. What is currently happening is that your regex is finding the first `{{`, then going *all* the way to the **very last** `}}` because it is "greedy."

Comment: Thanks for your speedy reply :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use a special character class like this instead of the dot:

```
String regex = "\\{\\{[^}]*+\\}\\}";
```

In other words `[^}]` means all character but `}`

Or you can use a lazy quantifier but it is less performant:

```
String regex = "\\{\\{.*?\\}\\}";
```

and you must work in single line mode.

Comment: +1 for suggesting the `[^}]`. It is a much better option than `.*?` here.

Comment: Thanks for your speedy reply :)

Comment: Why is it a better option? :X

Comment: @Wakka02: because when you use `.*?` the regex engine must test on each character that it is not a `}` and record a backtrack position in the case it is. When you use `[^}]` with a possessive quantifier (`*+`, I added it) the regex engine know that he doesn't have to record backtrack positions and take all characters he can. Thus it is faster. more informations here:http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html

Comment: `[^}]` is **so much faster** than `.*?` that this one should be mentioned just for completeness (like this answer does).